# Trying to Construct Phase Shift Circuit in Multisim

Tags: simulation, multisim, phase-shift, research

I'm attempting to construct the variable phase shift circuit from [this video](https://youtu.be/FHXZ9C914S0?t=130) (link takes you to the circuit diagram of it) within Multisim. As far as I can tell the circuits are identical, and yet my simulated circuit behaves very differently than the one shown in the video. Please, I am asking for help to determine why it is not working. I have included screenshots of the simulation with the potentiometer set to 0% and to 100%
thank you!
[image: Ciruit Diagram from Video]

[image: my simulation with the potentiometer set to 0%]

[image: my simulation with the potentiometer set to 100%]

Comment: Why is the collector resistor 20k instead of 2.2k ? Looks this high collector resistor is saturating the transistor

Comment: `circuits are identical` ... check the components one at a time to confirm that

Comment: You may find that the best balance is when the Rpot=2Re=2Rc

Comment: @across I have corrected that value and observe the same behavior?

Comment: @jsotola Yes, I Had an incorrect value for one of the resistors, I have now corrected that to no avail. Are you seeing anywhere else where I have used incorrect values?

Comment: @YaGoiRoot try reducing input to 0.1V. A large input can also saturate the transistor. You may like to see this simulation in circuit lab  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/610705/bjt-phase-shifter-working